# How to Integrate cutom web application with crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have developed one web application using .Net 4.0. I have hosted that application on CRM 2011 ISV server by creating virtual directory into it ,when i have call that by url as "/test.aspx" then it wont work.How to do that? Please provide any sample code.

Thanks in advance,
shekhar

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported any more in CRM 2011.

You only have two options to extend CRM:

1. By Creating Silverlight applications
2. By Creating HTML pages with JScript/jQuery/Json.

Answer (score 2):

It is not an easy task to say what might be wrong with your web app, when you do not tell us anything about what errors you are getting. Here is what I have done to get a web app running under ISV in CRM 2011.

As some already stated, this is deprecated in CRM 2011.

In your web.config file of your custom web application yous should remove crm.authentication and clear the httpModules.

```
<configSections>
   <remove name="crm.authentication" />
</configSections>

<httpModules>
   <clear/>
</httpModules>
```

You will also have to put a few dll's in the bin folder of your web app

- Microsoft.Crm.dll
- Microsoft.Crm.sdk.dll
- Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Sdk.dll
- Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy.dll
- Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll
- AntiXssLibrary.dll

Comment: configSections doesn't support remove item.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the ISV function is deprecated, but still supported in CRM 2011. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309571.aspx. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509061.aspx